# Extend the div present within td to beyond without affecting parent

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to display a div within td without actually affecting the dimensions of `<td>`.
Setting position to fixed/absolute doesn't allow the div to be scrolled along with td.

Adding code snippet for the problem

```css
td {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="width: 100px; height: 150px; background: yellow;">
        This should not affect parent td height
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Top 50px of this should be covered by yellow div
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yellow div needs to be absolutely positioned so that it doesn't affect the height of its parent element.

But, to position it in relation to the parent element you need that parent element to itself be positioned.

In this snippet I've colored the second td green so we can distinguish it from the first and also given the absolutely positioned div a width of 90px so we can tell where it is in relation to the two tds.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: red; position: relative;">
      <div style="width: 90px; height: 150px; background: yellow; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">
        This should not affect parent td height
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: green;">
      Top 50px of this should be covered by yellow div
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: As long as you don't specify either or several of `top`, `right`, `bottom` and/or `left`, the parent doesn't need to be positioned. `position: relative` on container elements is prone to cause alot of problems in layouts, so it should be avoided unless necessary.

Comment: @connexo that is true of a relatively positioned element, but an element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor - so you have to give the parent td a position if you want it positioned in relation to that.

Comment: No, that is incorrect. Remove `position: relative` along with `top: 0` and `left: 0` in your code and the output will stay identical. Just setting an element to `position: absolute` means "render it where it would appear without absolute position, but remove it from the document flow, that is, with regard to other elements, render it as though it had no dimensions".

Comment: @connexo but we should not rely on such behavior because it will change based on a lot of factor. explicitely setting the position is safer

Comment: @connexo, that right, position: relative is important and it seems to work now. Thanks

Comment: @TemaniAfif Disagreed. As long as "render it where it would appear without absolute position, but remove it from the document flow, that is, with regard to other elements, render it as though it had no dimensions" is exactly what you want, it is preferrable to not specify `position: relative` on the parent, as that is really wreaking havoc on alot of layout-related things, especially with regard to `overflow: auto/clip/scroll`.

Comment: @connexo see [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position If you remove the relative from the parent element in the snippet, the yellow div positions itself to the top/left, outside the parent in this case. i.e. it's had to go back up to the initial containing block. It's one of the differences between relative and absolute.

Comment: @connexo check this: https://jsfiddle.net/mpy523zL/ .. adding position:absolute moved the element to the bottom